# How to import functions from the interactive session namespace for timeit benchmarks?

Tags: python, benchmarking

I found the following example in Python's document.

```
def test():
    """Stupid test function"""
    L = []
    for i in range(100):
        L.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test"))
```

However that only works when the code is defined in a script. How can I test a function that is defined in a Python repl? Hope someone can point me the right direction. Below is my testing.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> dir(timeit)
['Timer', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__sp
ec__', '_globals', 'default_number', 'default_repeat', 'default_timer', 'dummy_src_name', 'gc', 'itertools', 'main', 're
indent', 'repeat', 'sys', 'template', 'time', 'timeit']
>>> help(timeit.timeit)
Help on function timeit in module timeit:

timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<built-in function perf_counter>, number=1000000, globals=None)
    Convenience function to create Timer object and call timeit method.

>>> timeit.timeit('''a=""; a+="b"*1000;''')
0.14870357161726633
>>> timeit.timeit('''a=""; a+="b"*1000;''')
0.13576636550958954
>>>
>>>
>>> def testme():
...     a = ""
...     a = "eyang" * 10000
...
>>> timeit("testme()")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
>>> timeit("testme()", setup="from __main__ import testme")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running an interactive console session aka REPL, *it* is the `__main__` module:

```
In [228]: def x():print "foo"

In [229]: from __main__ import x

In [230]: x()
foo
```

---

That said, in IPython, there's the `timeit` magic command that runs the code in the interactive namespace by default, saving you the need to type the set-up code.

Comment: I'm not using IPython, I'm using the normal Python console (open a command line window and type "python" followed by enter). I'm on Windows.

Comment: @user130268 the code works the same in the regular console. I only mention that there's a better solution.

Comment: As in my testing code shows, I've tested just using `timeit("testme()")` in the console and it does not work. Is this what you are saying? I omitted the setup part here.

Comment: @user130268 Ah! there's a typo in your last command. It should be `timeit.timeit()` rather than `timeit()`.

Comment: D'oh! Yes that's it! Thank you Ivan for the help!